# Localization with RPLider (Python)

Tags: python, localization, slam

we are currently messing around with an Slamtec RPLidar A1. We have a robot with the lidar mounted on it. 
Our aim is to retrieve a x and y position in the room. (it's a closed room, could have more than 4 corners but the whole room should be recognized once (it does not matter where the RPlidar stands).

Anyway the floormap is not given.
We got so far a x and y position with BreezySLAM but we recognized, wherever the RPlidar stands, it always sees itself as center, so we do not really know how to retrieve correct x and y from this information.

We are new to this topic and maybe someone can give us a good hint or link to find a simple solution.

PS: We are not intending to track the movement of the robot.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to record a map of your room and then use something like Monte Carlo Localization to localize your robot in it or just use a full SLAM algorithm.

If ROS is an option for you you can try the [Hector SLAM package](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam?distro=melodic) for full SLAM or for creating and saving a map of your room which you can then feed into the [AMCL package](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=melodic) to perform Monte Carlo Localization in it.

In either case the x and y position of your robot will be retrievable with respect to the origin of your room as it was created in the mapping part as a transformation between the map frame and the robot frame.

Answer (score 0):

Any sensor sees itself in the center of the environment. The idea of recording map is good one, if not. You can presume that any of the corners can be your zero points, you your room is not square, you can measure length of the wall and and you down to 2 points. Unfortunately if you don't have any additional markers in the environment or you can't create map before actual use, I'm afraid there is no chance for robot to correctly understand where is desired (0,0) point is.